# Where should I create a PID/lock file when writing a portable application

Tags: windows, linux, macos, file

I am modifying an application I have written to prevent multiple instances from running at the same time.

My first thought, was (according to [the Linux FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/)) to simply store a PID file in [`/var/run`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-5.13.html). In this way, I can check if the PID file exists, and exit with an error if it does.

Now, if I want my app to be portable, I have to consider that `/var/run` does not exist on every system (f.ex. Windows).

What is the best practice in this case?

**Note:** It does not have to be a PID file. A 0-byte "lock" file would do the trick as well. The PID file would have the advantage of also providing the PID to whomever would need to investigate problems.

**Clarification:** The application is a backup script which is normally run by a well defined user.

Comment: Also, for portable apps, can ordinary users run it? And can multiple ordinary users run it at the same time? Indeed, why do you need to block it from running multiple times?

Comment: No. It's a backup script which is either run directly by `root` or by a specific `backup` user. Depending on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is to make your application rely on a porting framework (like Qt). Such framework provides abstraction of the platform, allowing you to put always at "correct place" (e.g. for windows, it changes between XP, Vista/7). You might for example have a look at [QSettings](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qsettings.html#platform-specific-notes)
If you can't rely on a framework, then digging into their code might provide advanced answer.

Comment: `/var/run` on Linux has a specific meaning. It's not the same as `/etc`. I'm not storing settings here, Just runtime info. The most likely candidate OSs are Linux and Windows. I could just go ahead and, on Linux, store it in `/var/run` and on Windows store it in `%APPDATA%`. However, I am curious to see if Windows also has something similar to `/var/run`.

Comment: settings was an example of a cross-platform implementation of a generic concept, I understand /etc is not /var/run ;-)

Comment: While I agree, that this could be a solution, it seems a bit overkill to add a dependency to something as large as Qt only to determine the location for lock files. Don't you think? ;)

Comment: Of course! But if you target portability, you usually have to care about a lot more,than Qt is abstracting for you.

Answer (score 0):

how about a IPC object? IPC objects are systemwide, right? assume we have a IPC object named "pp1232fafdsafd", the second time we open it, linux would set errno to EEXIST. we can check errno to prevent multiple instances from running.

---

by lzh
hittlle@hotmail.com